# how to get the correct embedding from Roberta transformers?

Tags: bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I got confused by which hidden state should I use as the output of fine-tuned Roberta transformer models.

```
from transformers import AutoConfig, AutoModelForMaskedLM, AutoTokenizer
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
config.output_hidden_states = True

tok = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("roberta-base", config=config)

inp = "alright let s do this  "

sentence = tok.encode(inp, padding='max_length', max_length=512, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')

output = model(sentence)
```

According to Huggingface documentation for `RobertaForMaskedLM`:

Returns a tuple of:

1. masked_lm_loss (optional)
2. prediction_scores
3. hidden_states (optional)
4. attentions (optional)

By passing the config to enable hidden_states output, the `output` is a tuple of (`prediction_scores`, `hidden_states`)

My question is:
should I use `output[-1][0]` or `output[-1][-1]` as the final output embedding from the fine-tuned Roberta Model? My understanding is that `output[-1][0]` is the initial embedding feeding into the Roberta Model, and `output[-1][-1]` is the final embedding output.

Answer (score 0):

`output[-1][-1]` is correct if you are looking for the output of the last encoding layer. You can figure this out by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/6e8a38568eb874f31eb49c42285c3a634fca12e7/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L419) and validate it by comparing the output:

```py
import torch

print(len(output[-1]))

outputEmbeddings = model.roberta.embeddings(sentence)

#the first tensor is the output of the embedding layer
print(torch.equal(output[1][0],  outputEmbeddings))

#the second tensor is the output of the first encoding layer
print(torch.equal(output[1][1], model.roberta.encoder.layer[0](outputEmbeddings)[0]))

previousLayer = outputEmbeddings
for x in range(12):
    #it is now the current layer
    previousLayer = model.roberta.encoder.layer[x](previousLayer)[0]
    print(torch.equal(output[1][1+x], previousLayer))
```

Output:

```
13
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```